# When the table row is clicked, give me the value of groupno. but i cant find any solution

Tags: php, ajax

PHP code:

```
$data= $db->prepare("select * from user");
$data->execute();  
if($data -> rowCount()) {
    echo "<table border='1'> ";
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td>"
             .$row["lastname"]."</td><td>"
             .$row["phone"]."</td><td>"
             .$row["officephone"]."</td><td>"
             .$row["homephone"]."</td><td>"
             .$row["GrupNo"]."</td><td>"."</td></tr>";
     }
}
```

- I use the groupno value I get from the database
   The data I get from GroupNo,i will transfer inputs*

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to actually FETCH the result rows before attempting to process them

Comment: i suggest you start buy [looking at the manual, maybe `->fetchAll()` would be a good thing to use here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `$result = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: Also this would require some code refactoring in the output to make this simple line of code be any use to the OP